# Compile glide vendored packages

Tags: go, dependencies, vendor, golint

Golang's [glide](https://github.com/Masterminds/glide) downloads dependencies to the project's source. As a result, `go build` compiles those too, and go plugins that lint/vet the codebase also parse the dependencies.

Assuming those dependencies are stable, how can I compile the dependencies so `go build` becomes faster?

Also, how can I remove `vendor/` from go's tools to lint and check the codebase for errors?

Comment: What would be wrong with `go install` ? ANd running lint on a single package works perfectly fine. Maybe I do not understand your question?

Comment: I'm new to the language and ecosystem. Is there a way to pre-compile my dependencies (get `.a`) files, so it is faster to compile when I run `go install` or `go build`.

Comment: Yes, as I said, that is what `go install` does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to pre-compile my dependencies (get .a) files, so it is
>   faster to compile when I run go install or go build

See https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Compile_packages_and_dependencies

> go build [-o output] [-i] [build flags] [packages]

[...]

> The -i flag installs the packages that are dependencies of the target.

---

> Also, how can I remove vendor/ from go's tools to lint and check the
>   codebase for errors?

See https://github.com/golang/go/issues/11659#issuecomment-122139338:

> Instead of using ./... you can do:

`go install $(go list ./... | grep -v /vendor/)`

Comment: I appreciate all the links to documentation and development issues/solutions.